# Using Event on Drive menu

Tags: c#

I'm getting a couple of compilation errors, I don't know why, what am I doing wrong?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
    {
        Menu startMenu = new Menu() { Title = "Enter a drive" };

        // The error is here: Invalid initializer member declarator
        MenuItem d = new MenuItem() {Text = "{0}" , drive.Name};

        if (drive.IsReady)
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = 5;
            Console.Write(drive.VolumeLabel);
        }

        // another error: 'System.IO.DriveInfo' does not contain a definition for 'Selected' and no extension method 'Selected' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.DriveInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
        drive.Selected += drive_Selected;

        startMenu.Items = new[] {d};
        startMenu.Show();
    }
}

private static void drive_Selected()
{
}
```

Comment: Do people downvoting think they help newbies ? There are no stupid questions ...

Answer (score 1):

**First error** - you should provide property name of `MenuItem` in class initializer

```
MenuItem d = new MenuItem() {Text = "{0}" , YourPropertyName = drive.Name};
```

Or simply assign drive name to `Text` property (if you just tried to do some formatting, because "{0}" for text looks odd for me)

```
MenuItem d = new MenuItem() {Text = drive.Name };
```

**Second error** - `DriveInfo` does not have `Selected` event or any other events. It just holds information about drive. And drive does not know that you have 'selected' it somewhere. Suppose you need to add `Selected` event to your`MenuItem` class.

But anyway why not to use WinForms or WPF for this task? You will have to do lot of work for creating this kind of menu in console application.